# Why there save and load file code works on iphone simulator but failed on device

Tags: iphone, sdk

```
(void) loadDataFromDisk
{
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self pathToDataFile]];
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];


    _cells = [[unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"Board"] retain];

    [unarchiver release];
    [data release]; 
}

(void) saveDataToDisk
{   
    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData alloc];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    [archiver encodeObject:_cells forKey:@"Board"];

    [archiver finishEncoding];

    [data writeToFile:[self pathToDataFile] atomically:YES];

    //[array release];  
    [data release];
    //NSMutableData 
}

(BOOL)gameDataExists
{
    return [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self pathToDataFile]];
}

(NSString *)pathToDataFile
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    return [path stringByAppendingPathComponent: GAME_DAT];
}
```

the code above worked on simulator but failed on device.it seems like that the file can not
be found after i exit and reload my app.
And if i implement the pathToDataFile like this:

```
(NSString *)pathToDataFile
{
    NSArray * path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDir = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    return [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:GAME_DAT];
}
```

the file save and reload worked on device ,but the drawRect method i implemented in my view can not be called after i called [self setNeedsDisplay].

chris
Can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bundle path is read-only on the device but read-write on the emulator.  On the device any attempts to write there will therefore fail.

Your second approach to use document directory should solve the problem.

I don't know why [self setNeedsDisplay] doesn't work for you but it's likely unrelated to this problem.

There is one error I noticed in your code:

```
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData alloc];
```

Should be:

```
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
```

You should also release the archiver at the end of the saveDataToDisk method.

Comment: Thanks,but my problem is that if i change the pathToDataFile function,my view can not be displayed properly,it can not run into the drawRect function i write.